# Android NDK : ndk-build building error

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk

I'm starting to use the android ndk (r8c), and for that I have installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 12.10 (32bit)
Problem, whatever I try to build, I got freaky errors that drive me crazy...

> ~/workspace/Test$ ndk-build
>
> Compile thumb  : Test <= Test.c
>   SharedLibrary  : libTest.so arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error:
>   ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/Test/Test.o: No such file or directory make:
>   *** [obj/local/armeabi/libTest.so] Error 1

So here, I try to run ndk-build on a simple hello world in jni. I can't understand the problem, as I thought the ndk-build command was suppose to create Test.o itself...
So I tried the same thing with ndk-r7 (we never know), and it is even uglier...

> ~/workspace/Test$ ~/Code/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build
>
> Compile thumb  :
>   Test <= Test.c Messages de l'assembleur: Erreur fatale: option -march=
>   invalide: « armv5te » make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/Test/Test.o]
>   Erreur 1

I can't find any answer that seems to help. (I've also tried to build hello-jni sample the same way, but the output was the same.

Please, someone save my hair... Hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: Do you want to build a shared library? Why do you use a old NDK version (the error is from ndk-r7) ?

Comment: The first command was made with the current version of NDK (version 8c), and the second one with NDK7, just to try. I'm not trying to build a shared library, this is just a hello world to try making ndk work.

Comment: Then you need to specify that in your Android.mk, `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)` instead of lib

Comment: I guess you mean to replace include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) by include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE) at the end of Android.mk? If so, this doesn't change anything

Comment: Please show your `jni/Android.mk` file and `jni/Application.mk`, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to reinstall my ubuntu, and it worked well this time.

I still have no idea why it didn't the first time, as I think I have done exactly the same manipulation (I went to Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 12.10 though).